# Set the frame of the MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 3.1.x

Tags: iphone, view, mpmovieplayercontroller, frame

I have been trying to set the frame of the MPMoviePlayerController. But the app is crashing at the line `player.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,480,320);` in iOS 3.1.3 but works fine on iOS 3.2 or greater. What might be the problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aVideo.mp4" ofType:@""]];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
        // Use the new 3.2 style API
        moviePlayer.repeatMode = YES;
         moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    } 
    else {
         Use the old 2.0 style API
       moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,480,320);
        [self.view addSubview: [moviePlayer view]];
        moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        [moviePlayer play];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPMoviePlayerController reference clearly states the view property is available from iOS3.2 onwards.

> `view`
>
> The view containing the movie content
>   and controls. (read-only)
>
> `@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This property contains the view used
>   for presenting the video content. This
>   view incorporates all the background,
>   content, and controls needed to
>   display movies. You can incorporate
>   this view into your own view
>   hierarchies or present it by itself
>   using a view controller.
>
> To embed the view into your own view
>   hierarchies, add it as a subview to
>   one of your existing views. A good
>   place to do this is in the loadView or
>   viewDidLoad method of the custom view
>   controller that presents your view
>   hierarchy. You are free to change the
>   view’s frame rectangle to accommodate
>   the space available in your view
>   hierarchy. The movie player uses the
>   value in the scalingMode property to
>   scale the movie content to match the
>   frame you specify.
>
> If you want to present the view by
>   itself—that is, without embedding it
>   in an existing view hierarchy—you can
>   use an instance of the
>   MPMoviePlayerViewController class to
>   manage the presentation of the view.
>   That class works directly with the
>   movie player controller to present the
>   view by itself.
>
> You can add subviews to the view in
>   this property. You might do this in
>   cases where you want to display custom
>   playback controls or add other custom
>   content that is relevant to your
>   application.
>
> **Availability**
>
> - Available in iOS 3.2 and later.

And for iOS 3.1

> **Behavior in iOS 3.1 and Earlier**
>
> In iOS 3.1 and earlier, this class
>   implemented a full-screen movie player
>   only. After creating the movie player
>   and initializing it with a single
>   movie file, you called the play method
>   to present the movie. (The definition
>   of the play method has since moved out
>   of this class and into the
>   MPMediaPlayback protocol.) The movie
>   player object itself handled the
>   actual presentation of the movie
>   content.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of crash is it? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Yeah.. SIGABRT  NSObject does not recognise selector after the line that I set the frame.

Comment: Can post the code you're using above? And also the selector? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding the player view to two different views in the // 3.2 style API (you're not for the 2.0)? Can you let us know what playerView is? Thanks.

Comment: P.s. You also say the app is crashing at the line "player.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,480,320);" but I don't see this in your example. :S

Comment: I have been trying out different ways to avoid the crash. I have updated the code.

Comment: This is an immediate problem I notice: moviePlayer.view.setFrame = CGRectMake (0,0,480,320); There is no property "setFrame", there is a property "frame" (if this doesn't make sense I'd advise reading the Property Programming Guide by Apple).

Comment: If the above wasn't clear enough. I mean, try: moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,480,320);

Comment: Also, please ensure the size of moviePlayer.view.frame is the same size as self.view (see if this solves the issue).

Comment: Ok. Can you add the exception thread trace that's printed on the crash? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**view** property available in iOS 3.2 and later for **MPMoviePlayerController**.